# Pyramid Graph only showing the larger values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have made a pyramid graph that has stacked bars. However, for some reason, only the bigger values are being shown.
Here is the graph:

[image: Pyramid Stacked Graph]

Here is the code:

```
 ggplot(data = dataf, aes(x = age, y = total, fill = loc)) +
  geom_bar(data = dataf %>% filter(gender == "Mujer") %>% arrange(loc),
           stat = "identity",
           position = "identity") +
  geom_bar(data = dataf %>% filter(gender == "Hombre") %>% arrange(loc),
           stat = "identity",
           position = "identity",
           mapping = aes(y = -total)) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = abs)+
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, colour="white", lwd=1)
```

I would appreciate it is anyone had any ideas on what to do. Essentially, Aranjuez has data but is smaller than all the rest of them and for some reason it does not show.

Additionally, if anyone has suggestions on how to change the labels on the y-axis, I would be really grateful.

Thank you.

Comment: The bars in your plot are overlapping one another, rather than stacking on top of one another, hence only the larger ones are visible. Remove `position = "identity"` from your code & `geom_bar()` will default to `position = "stack"`.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was perfect! Interesting, what made you think that, that was the solution?

Comment: By having made more strange mistakes in ggplot, only earlier. :)